# Longest straight in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I came across a programming challenge that has been tearing me up for those. It's named "dice straight".

Basically, you're given m x 6 matrices (the column length is always 6 but the rows vary), and you're to find the length of the longest string of adjacent integers that can be formed picking **one** integer from **each** row. That means, you can't take 2 integers from one row and you can't leave a row out.

For example, one of the matrix is

```
[4  8  15 16 23 42]
[8  6  7  5  30 9 ]
[1  2  3  4  55 6 ]
[2  10 18 36 54 86]
```

The longest straight can be formed taking 2 from row4, 3 from row3, 4 from row1 and 5 from row 2. That's 2,3,4,5. So it returns 4, the length.

The code I have now works for the above matrix and moderately sized matrices, but when it gets to 100 x 6 matrices, it runs forever. I'm using a combination of  back track algorithm and depth first. First, I combine the rows into one array and sort them, then, using a stack, I pick numbers on the condition that it's adjacent to the stack top and it's not on the same row as any integer in the stack, and when it reaches a dead-end, I dequeue until I get to last working solution.

```java
static int maxLength(Face[] faces, int d){
    faces = quickSort(faces, 0, faces.length - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < faces.length - 1; i++) {
        if(faces[i].side == faces[i+1].side && faces[i].dice > faces[i+1].dice){
            Face temp = faces[i];
            faces[i] = faces[i+1];
            faces[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(faces.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
        //System.out.print(faces[i]+"  ");
    }
    int maxLength = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
        Stack<Face> tree = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> dices = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> sides = new Stack<>();
        int length = 1;
        tree.add(faces[i]);
        dices.add(faces[i].dice);
        sides.add(faces[i].side);
        int pos = i;
        //System.out.print(faces[pos].side + ", ");
        while(!tree.isEmpty() && pos < faces.length - 1){
            pos++;
            //System.out.println(faces[pos] + "}"+faces[pos + 1]);
            if(faces[pos].side - faces[pos - 1].side == 2){
                for(Face ig : tree){
                    //System.out.print(ig+" ");
                }
                //System.out.println("/"+faces[pos]+"/"+length);
                i = pos;
                break;
            }
            faces[pos].visited = true;
            //System.out.print(tree.peek().side + " ");
            if(!dices.contains(faces[pos].dice) && faces[pos].side - tree.peek().side == 1){
                tree.push(faces[pos]);
                dices.push(faces[pos].dice);
                //System.out.print(faces[pos].side + " ");
                length++;
                maxLength = Math.max(length, maxLength);
                if(maxLength == d){
                    i = 5000000;
                    //System.out.println("beeeeeee");
                    //System.out.println(tree.size());
                    for(Face ig : tree){
                        //System.out.print(ig+" ");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }else if(faces[pos].side - tree.peek().side == 2){
                Face a = tree.peek();
                Face x = tree.pop();
                //System.out.println(tree.peek()+"|"+x+"|"+length+"|"+faces[pos]);
                pos = Arrays.asList(faces).indexOf(x)+1;
                dices.pop();
                length--;
                for(Face ig : tree){
                    //System.out.println(ig);
                }
                //System.out.println();
            }else if(faces[pos].side - tree.peek().side > 2){

            }

        }
        //System.out.println();
        for(Face ig : tree){
            //System.out.println(ig);
        }
    }

    return maxLength;
}
```

"Face" is a class with 2 fields. 'Side', which represents the integer in a row i and dice, which represents 'i'. Face[] is an array of all the elements in the matrix, sorted in ascending order of 'side'. So Face[] for the above matrix would be

1(2) 2(2) 2(3) 3(2) 4(0) 4(2) 5(1) 6(1) 6(2) 7(1) 8(0) 8(1) 9(1) 10(3) 15(0) 16(0) 18(3) 23(0) 30(1) 36(3)  42(0) 54(3) 55(2) 86(3) in x(y) format where x is side and y is dice.

I found the challenge in the link below. If you don't understand my question, please check this. 
https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6314486/dashboard#s=p0&a=0

I'll very much appreciate it if anyone points me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: There is an editorial page for those problems, have you taken a look at it? [Editorial](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6314486/dashboard#s=a)

Comment: Oh, yes. If you're talking about the problem analysis, I've read it. I couldn't learn much. Got lost at Ford-Fulkerson. Tried looking it up on Wikipedia but I hardly understood a thing. I'm hoping someone would simulate a small version of this problem and the solution and explain the algorithm he used. Or perhaps point me in the right direction if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Look, the hard truth is these kind of problem need to making used of basic algorithm creatively, as a building block to attack the problem, even more, this problem is designed to be solved by the top 25 people in the world, not for everyone.So if you don't have a strong algo foundation, the chances to understand, not even to solve it is very slim. So my advice is take a step back, try to fully understand and use these building blocks effectively, then come back to give this another try.

Comment: The original problem does not have the constraint that you "can't leave a row out".  (If it did, the answer would always be the total number of rows!)  I have to agree with Pham Trung -- if someone "explained the algorithm they used" to you, they would necessarily have to explain the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm as part of that explanation.  (Or if you are prepared to accept the F-F algorithm as a black box that simply finds an optimal bipartite matching, then the editorial page already explains everything.)

Comment: You are both right. I've stopped trying already, 'cos I realize this may be a little way out of my league. @j_random_hacker, yes, that was a mistake. You can leave a row out if it doesn't add to the straight. Thanks guys.

Comment: I hope we didn't put you off programming challenges completely!  Start with some easier problems and put in some work, and gradually your league will expand :)  The key really is finding a series of problems that you can *only just* solve -- this will expand your skill set.  Easier said than done of course!